# Tag not available

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

**Problem**: I just noticed that there’s a [high-avability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-avability) tag with 1 follower, no tag wiki and no usage guidance. It’s obviously a mis-spelling of *high-availability* (which doesn’t exist as a tag).

**Suggested solution**: Since there are only 16 questions, it wouldn’t be too much work to manually edit each question. However, this would “bump” each question to the top of the active question list so I thought I’d first ask here to check if there’s a better way of fixing this issue.

Comment: I volunteer to edit one a day. It’ll be lost in the noise of my other editing :)

Comment: @Jeff Very good. :)  I'll keep my own edits spaced out a bit.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no need, I merged the tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just merged [high-avability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-avability) into [high-availability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-availability). There should now be no questions tagged [high-avability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-avability) and the tag will be deleted by the system.

So no need to edit.